# How to display compact view in Xcode preview?

Tags: xcode, swiftui

By default, Xcode would use a device's screen to show live preview. For example:

[image]

How can I enable compact mode to only display the control I'm working with ?

Comment: Totally covered by the Previews talk at WWDC 2019.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `.previewLayout(.sizeThatFits)` for the view you are previewing:

```swift
struct ContentView_Previews : PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
            .previewLayout(.sizeThatFits)
    }
}
```

Then you will see:

[image]